# How to set the fix time for the pop up window in php

Tags: php, html

I have written code like this

```
setTimeout('newWindow.close();',1000);
```

But this code does not work. 
It does not give any errors but the pop-up is not destroyed.

Can anybody help me ?

Comment: You can't close a window with php. PHP is server side. You will need to use JavaScript to do it as you have tried. You need to post more detail for people to help you. Like where you are executing that script and how the popup window is created in the first place.

Comment: You do it like this -> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dMsW3/), and avoid strings in timeouts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this within script tags in your php code

setTimeout('window.close()', 2000);